# How to write regex in php for changing content?

Tags: php, regex

I have a .h file which contains hundred of lines code. I want to get back the strings from the variable.

```
string PackageToRun[][] = { {"M16.1","M16.1EP1","M16.2","M17"},
            {"Tv16.2","Tv17","Ta17","Ta16.2 MOpenTAS","Tv17.1","Ta17.1","T16.2","T16.2c"} };
```

Is it possible to write a Regex in PHP which get back "M16.1","M16.1EP1" ... ?!
If it's possible, will it work if I'm adding more string to PackageToRun ?!

Comment: It is possible and yes if you write it right it will work even if you add more string to PackageToRun !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey that sort of looks like JSON!

```
<?php 

$file = '
string PackageToRun[][] = { {"M16.1","M16.1EP1","M16.2","M17"},
            {"Tv16.2","Tv17","Ta17","Ta16.2 MOpenTAS","Tv17.1","Ta17.1","T16.2","T16.2c"} };
';

if( preg_match('#string PackageToRun\[\]\[\] = ({.*});#is', $file, $matches)) {
  $data = json_decode(str_replace(array('{','}'), array('[',']'), $matches[1]));
  print_r($data);
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => M16.1 [1] => M16.1EP1 [2] => M16.2 [3] => M17 
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Tv16.2 [1] => Tv17 [2] => Ta17 [3] => Ta16.2 MOpenTAS 
        [4] => Tv17.1 [5] => Ta17.1 [6] => T16.2 [7] => T16.2c 
    ) 
)
```